# Clarification: Gradient and Hessian of $g(x) = \sum_i g_i(x_i)$; $x = [x_1,\ldots,x_N]^T \in \mathbb{R}^N$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

I would like to clarify the Gradient and Hessian of $$g(x) = \sum_i g_i(x_i) ,$$ where $x = [x_1,\ldots,x_N]^T \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

- Is the gradient of $g(x)$ correct? 
  $$\nabla g(x) = \left[ \nabla g_1(x_1), \ldots, \nabla g_i(x_i), \ldots,  \nabla g_N(x_N) \right]^T \ .$$
- Is the Hessian of $g(x)$ correct?
  $$\mathcal{H}\left( g(x) \right) = {\rm Diag} \left\{ \nabla^2 g_1(x_1), \ldots, \nabla^2 g_i(x_i), \ldots,  \nabla^2 g_N(x_N) \right\} \ ,$$
  where ${\rm Diag}\{ \cdot \}$ creates the diagonal matrix of the elements.

Comment: The gradient of $g$ is an $n$ dimensional vector whereas here you defined the gradient of $g$ as a sum of $1$ dimensional vectors, so the gradient is : $(\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_1}, ..., \frac{\partial g_n}{\partial x_n})$

Comment: Oh Thank you. How about the Hessian?